# Do field types for Django's models have any kind of field that behaves like JavaScript's Numbers?

Tags: javascript, django

Whether this is a good or bad feature, JavaScript programmers of any competency usually know that JavaScript does not have a usual division of labor where one or more integer types of possibly varying precision are defined, and where one or more floating point number types of possibly varying precision are defined. Instead, Numbers behave like a pure integer type without any rounding errors or 1 + 2 !== 3 as long as you stick with integers within a certain relatively large range, but behave like floats if you do arithmetic options that will have a non-integer value or result (like 1.23 or 1 / 2).

Are there any field types available for Django that behave like a JavaScript Number? If they're not built in but available with someone's package, what's that package?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "behave like"? Are you talking specifically about how it's formatted when presented to the user? If so, that might merely be a question of using a floating-point type at the database / Python level and then passing it through a custom filter at the template level.

Comment: Mm, to change my original intent behind the request: whatever the internal representation may be, the enduser effect is that what is meant as an integer is *displayed* as an integer, and most floating point values will be *displayed* as floating point, under conditions where imprecision in arithmetic doesn't add up. I imagine that if a standard floating point does not store integers like 3 in some small range, testing for near equality to an integer for some epsilon value would be good enough for government work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't.

Django's model fields store data in the database using the database's native types. The purpose of a "field type" is to tell Django, "When saving this, save it as this type." They also specify how the value stored should be mapped back into a native Python type.

So, since a database like Postgres doesn't have a "magic" Number storage type, and because Python doesn't have a native "magic" Number type, it would not make sense to have a Django field type that represented a magic type.

Instead, you just have to pick an integer type to store your data as, and stick to it whenever reading or writing that field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way to get what you're after is to use a [`FloatField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield) for storage and a custom template filter for display.

Python floats have an [`is_integer()` method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) that makes it easy to tell whether the float is exactly equivalent to an integer. Your [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) would look something like this:

```
def intify(value):
    return int(value) if value.is_integer() else value
```

Another option would to be to write a [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) that inherits from `FloatField` and converts the value into either a Python `int` or `float` depending on the specific value. However, I'd be wary of allowing the underlying Python type to change since there are situations where `int` and `float` behave differently.